# WebAPI V1 4.0.30506 incorrect on Nuget? Really Version 4.0.20918

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget

I'm looking for the last Webapi v1 for Framework 4.0, as per Nuget there should be a version 4.0.3056.

Downloading the package gives me Dll's with version 4.0.20918 which is from the prior release. I binary compare shows them as identical. 
Seems the fact the entire 4.0.3 stack is is 4.0.2 (Core\Client\Http)

Anybody know how to get the DLL's or build them from source?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/4.0.30506
and
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/4.0.20918

Kind Regards,
Mike

Comment: How did you install this package? I've just installed 4.0.30506 and got 4.0.30506. All works fine

Comment: I was downloading it in Visual Studio and the Directory does say 4.0.3, but right click the DLL and look at the property for version in the lib dir in the packages dir. You can also use the Download button (left side) on the Nuget pages from above two links

Comment: Also, The digital timestamp on the assumed 4.0.3 version is Sept 18, 2012 when the 4.0.3 version was released in May of 2013? (BTW, if you download the package manually above, rename .nuget to .zip)